# Running Self-contained .net-core Executable Not Responding to Requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am following a tutorial and have compiled a .net standalone app and sent it to my Ubuntu 16.10 server. Now I am running the app and everything seems to work correctly

```
$ ./MvcMovie
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/nnkuu/CEPublished/publish
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

But when I try to access the server through my web browser on http:// SERVER_IP:5000, the browser cannot establish the connection. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by making nginx function as a proxy that forwards traffic from port 80 on the external interface to port 5000 on the internal interface where the .net application is listening. This was done by running nginx with the following configuration file:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name <server_name or IP address>;

    location / {
              proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the server is listening on `http://localhost:5000`. That means that if you access the app from the same machine as `http://localhost:5000`, it will work, but it won't work if you access it from another machine.

What you need to do is to change the URL the app is listening on. The simplest way is to add the following line to the `WebHostBuilder` setup in your `main` method:

```
.UseUrls("http://*:5000")
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using nginx to forward the request from the internal external network interface to the internal instead, though.